# How to use math operators from commandline in program?

Tags: java

I try to calculate digits (in my calculator) in args from commandline. Example:

```
args[0] = 2*3;
String result = method(args[0]);
System.out.println(result) // should be 6
```

I don't know how to use my char between two digits example "+", "-". I can't use loops. My method idea is use **charAt** like:

```
char a = arg.charAt(0);
char b = arg.charAt(1);
char c = arg.charAt(2);
```

But I don't know to change my b char (*) to do calculation.

Comment: "I musn't use loops" ... Is this a homework you've gotten?

Comment: Is `args[0]` meant to be `6` or is it meant to be the string `"2*3"`? I guess it's the latter. Can you have more than one operator? Parenthesis? If not, you simply split by your operator to get the integers (assuming they're integers) and do the operator operation on them.

Comment: How about regular expressions? You should give that a try.

Comment: In command line: **2*3**, method should returning **6**.

Comment: @OriLentz yes, I can have more than one operator and parenthesis.

Comment: I don’t understand the question. When you want 2*3 to yield 6, it sounds like a calculation — so should 2+3 yield 5? When you say you want to count digits, there are only 2 digits in your example, not 6. There should be libraries out there that can parse expressions like 2*3 and 2+3 and calculate the result. Use your favourite search engine if this is what you are after.

Comment: Then you need to better define your question (it's definitely not about counting digits). Give a more complex example. I don't see how you can solve a complex one with parenthesis and many operators without the use of a loop or recursion (which is basically the same thing).

Comment: I don't know how to better define you that. It's calculator from arguments in command line. Hmm, maybe better example. My arg is 1/2 and the result (string) of the program should be 0.5.

Comment: That's still the same example, you just changed the operator. Give one that has more than operator and parenthesis, I doubt you'll be able to achieve what you want without loops (unless you limit the expression somehow).

Comment: Ohh, maybe it's too hard. I don't know, if that calculate with one operator is possible I try to make it that, withoud more parenthesis..

Comment: I believe you have already got answers working for one operator and no parentheses. If you agree, please click the check mark on the answer(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the value correctly. Your input is a String, right? Your code shows an integer expression.

```
args[0] = "2*3"; //note that this changed to a string
double result = parse(args[0]);
System.out.println(result) // should be 6
```

Then you can parse your string in your method:

```
double parse(String str){
  int num1 = Integer.valueOf(str.substring(0,1));
  char operator = str.charAt(1);
  int num2 = Integer.valueOf(str.substring(2,3));
  switch(operator){
    case '+': return num1+num2;
    case '-': return num1-num2;
    case '*': return num1*num2;
    case '/': return num1/num2;
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
```

Running `System.out.println(parse("2*3"));` prints `6.0` with my code.

Of course this only works with operands that have exactly one digit. But that's a restriction that comes from your `charAt` idea.

Comment: Ok, maybe better example. My arg is 1/2 and the result of the program should be 0.5. Thats better @f1sh ? IntelliJ told that args in commandline are strings..

Comment: When you want divisions to work as well, you need to work with something like a double. I'll update my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not normally using JAVA, but..

You will get the input as a string, if you run a process like this:

```
> MyCalculator 2*3
```

now, you want to separate this string into three parts:
`Number1, Operation, Number2` 
for this you can do something like:

```
String[] parts = args[0].split("\\*");
Double Number1 = Double.parseDouble( parts[0])
Double Number2 = Double.parseDouble( parts[1])
```

now, you may notice that you'll be missing the operator..
so you want locate it and fetch it, or you can do something like this:

```
if( args[0].indexOf("*") > -1)
{
    System.out.println(Number1  * Number2);
}
```

edit:
for more flexibillity, you may want to do it the opposite way around:

```
if( args[0].indexOf("*") > -1)
{
    String[] parts = args[0].split("\\*");
    Double Number1 = Double.parseDouble( parts[0])
    Double Number2 = Double.parseDouble( parts[1])
    System.out.println(Number1  * Number2);
}

if( args[0].indexOf("/") > -1)
{
    String[] parts = args[0].split("/");
    Double Number1 = Double.parseDouble( parts[0])
    Double Number2 = Double.parseDouble( parts[1])
    System.out.println(Number1  / Number2);
}
```

etc...

notice that "-" will be especially annoying

Answer (score 0):

Its not the best solution but it works, you can enter numbers of any length.

```
String[] number = args[0].split("[*]|[/]|[+]|[-]");
int stringLength = args[0].length();
int operatorBeginning = number[0].length();
int operatorEnd = stringLength - number[1].length();
String operator = args[0].substring(operatorBeginning,operatorEnd);

double answer = 0;

switch(operator) {
     case "*":
          answer = Integer.valueOf(number[0]) * Integer.valueOf(number[1]);
          break;
     case "/":
          answer = Integer.valueOf(number[0]) / Integer.valueOf(number[1]);
          break;
     case "+":
          answer = Integer.valueOf(number[0]) + Integer.valueOf(number[1]);
          break;
     case "-":
          answer = Integer.valueOf(number[0]) - Integer.valueOf(number[1]);
          break;
     default:
          System.out.println("Wrong operator");
          break;
}

System.out.println(answer);
```